# Azure Function JsonConvert Document Spatial Point

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have a model which has a property which uses a type of Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point.

```
public class TelemetryLiveExample
{
[JsonProperty("location")]
public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to serialize & deserialize the message using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.  If I serialize the following model locally for example.

```
TelemetryLiveExample telemetryLive = new TelemetryLiveExample
{
Location = new Point(1, 2)
};
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryLive);
```

I get the following result which is what I would expect as the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point has a custom converter PositionJsonConverter

```
"{"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1.0,2.0]}}"
```

If I do exactly the same but publish it to an Azure Function first I get the following result.  This looks like the custom converter is been ignored in the Azure function but I cannot figure out why.

```
{"location":{"Position":{"Coordinates":[1.0,2.0],"Longitude":1.0,"Latitude":2.0,"Altitude":null},"Crs":{"Name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84","Type":0},"Type":0,"BoundingBox":null,"AdditionalProperties":{}}}
```

I want to figure out why the Azure Function serializer ignores the custom converter and gives different results?

Comment: Where do you register this custom converter?

Comment: It's a custom converter which is part of theMicrosoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial namespace on the class Position used by the points class.  [JsonConverter(typeof(PositionJsonConverter))]
public sealed class Position : IEquatable<Position>  It is not one I have personally created.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.spatial.position?view=azure-dotnet) say `Position` exists in two different libraries: `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core.dll` and `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll`.  Is there any chance that you're using different versions locally and on azure and that there's an inconsistency between the two, e.g. using different versions of Json.NET?

Comment: @dbc thanks.  This is something I hadn't seen and I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to figure out why the Azure Function serializer ignores the custom converter and gives different results?

Based on my test, there is no different between azure function and locally. I test with following demo code and with nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/).

```
 public static class TestDocument
    {
        [FunctionName("TestDocument")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            TelemetryLiveExample telemetryLive = new TelemetryLiveExample
            {
                Location = new Point(1, 2)
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryLive);

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  My dependancy tree is as follows Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb 1.19.1
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 2.1.0-beta1
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.2
morelinq 2.8.0
Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3
StackExchange.Redis 1.2.6
WindowsAzure.Storage 8.5.0.  I will strip away all extra dependency's and try and isolate it.